# How to automatically generate anchor ids to CKEditor added headers

Tags: wysiwyg

How can i automatically generate anchor ids to h2 and h3 added using ck editor ?
I need it for making a table of content.

Comment: Not sure if anyone has built an integration module for this, but I would leverage https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/toc

Comment: interesting but would probably create a toc for each content type fields. A module would be needed to generate a toc for the full page , including paragraphs etc . I have maded it in JS

Comment: I've been looking for a plugin that lets authors assign/change ID attributes to any selected element via the UI; it would extend this nicely. CKE4 doesn't have it, but @rhystubbs created a plugin to do this in CKE5: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/7369

Answer (score 0):

in JS, id set from the h2 label two first words :

```
const headings = document.querySelectorAll(
  ".article--full h2, .article--full h3"
);
const tocElements = createTocElementsArray(headings);

function createTocElementsArray(headings) {
  const tocElements = [];   
  for (const item of headings) {
    if (item.id === "") {
      item.id = item.firstChild.data
        .split(" ")
        .slice(0, 2)
        .join("-");
    }
....
}
```

Comment: There's a safer example of this method on SO that checks if the ID exists before assigning it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257668/how-to-add-css-classes-and-an-id-to-paragraphs-in-ckeditor